# Как перенести данные из Excel на сайт

Tags: html, excel

Как перенести данные, находящиеся в Excel (текст и картинка), так, чтобы на сайте они отобразились в конкретных блоках, для текса и изображения соответственно?
Есть ли какие-то решения по этому поводу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все что хранится на сайте, храниться в БД. Для того что бы перенести данные из Excel в БД, используйте экспорт в БД. (такой функционал есть в любой БД). Сами картинки храните на сервере, предварительно указав в нужных блоках путь к картинке с помощью HTML. (тег img.), А данные подтягивайте из БД на сайт с помощью PHP и запросов SQL. ВСЕ.

Comment: А еще рекомендую изучить базовый HTML, SQL и PHP - это не так много времени занимает. Это базовые знания (начальные по созданию сайтов) используя базы данных.

Comment: "Все что хранится на сайте, храниться в БД." - бредятина чистейшей воды, я бы сказал - жесточайший антипатерн. Каждый инструмент для своих вещей, есть релаяционные БД, хранить в них файлы - плохо. Есть хранилища ключ значение - хранить в них объекты поиск по которым нужен по частичным полям - плохо. Есть файловые хранилища - хранить в них json по которому нужен поиск - ужасная идея. Есть хранилища кэша - хранить в них что либо кроме "кэша" - плохая идея. И это я только по термину БД прошелся. (который в вашем понимании из базы данных превратился в реляционные базы данных с SQL синтаксисом)

Comment: Я имел ввиду ТОЛЬКО текст хранить в БД. А про файлы сказал хранить на сервере. Можно указать путь к файлам (картинкам) с помощью HTML.

Comment: Я процитировал ваш же ответ "все что хранится на сайте"... ну допустим речь про текст - хранить текст в РСУБД - ужасная идея если вам не нужен полнотекстовый поиск или индексация текста. Такие штуки лучше хранить в специализированных СУБД(с нужными для вашей задачи возможностями). Поимите РСУБД которые вы пытаетесь использовать как универсальное хранилище - для такого не предназначены, у них ОЧЕНЬ узкая специализация :)

Comment: Я старался человеку порекомендовать наиболее простенький вариант. Тем более не было учтено объем такой таблицы. Может там такая таблица нужна, что бы на сайте отображалась, что можно и вовсе одним HTML обойтись :)

Comment: Самый простой вариант для человека - сделать в лоб как он хочет(отображать прям из экселя), если хотите подсказать верное решение - уточните какую проблему решает человек, сейчас ответ выглядит как сборник того как делать не надо :)

Comment: По html, js более менее силён, php подтянем. Таблица всего-дишь из 25 пунктов и все. Идею с бд тоже рассматриваю, т.к. на сайте имеется. Но можно ли сделать все легче, по типу преобразования excel в формат .html, накладывания небольших стилей на него и отображения на сайте?

Comment: Короче говоря на странице отобразить другую страницу с таблицей и применить к ней css? Ведь даже при сохранении в формате .html стили получаются топорные и хочется их изменить